# rexexp solution for php

Tags: php, regex

I have tried to work this out myself (even bought a Kindle book!), but I am struggling with backreferences in php.

What I want is like the following example:

```
var $html = "hello %world|/worldlink/% again";

output:
hello <a href="/worldlink/">world</a> again
```

I tried stuff like:

```
preg_replace('/%([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)%/', '<a href="\2">\1</a>', $html);
```

but with no joy.

Any ideas please? I am sure someone will post the exact answer but I would like an explanation as well please - so that I don't have to keep asking these questions :)

Comment: Define "no joy". What _exactly_ did you try, and what _exactly_ was the result?

Comment: I have tidied up your question a little. Please take the time to do the little things like capitalising `i`s; it's just a little courtesy to those who will spend time answering your question. I also note that there are _good_ solutions to most of your 21 questions, but you have only accepted answers to 25% of them.

Comment: With regards to your first comment, I assumed, apparently wrongly, that any experienced regex expert could take my attempt and try it for themselves. Sorry if I assumed wrongly. With regards to your second comment, I actually take offence at your "correcting" attitude. If I spoke with slang in person would you correct me then too? Also, I had a look at my other questions and bar the odd one, the actual answers didn't work - some of which I actually mentioned and asked for more help. My questions are legible and polite but for your benefit I have "written" this one in the Queens English.

Comment: (1) I'm sure they could, but since you've already done it you can save them time by informing them of your results. (2) I did not say "correcting". I said "tidied up" which is precisely what I did. As I say, it's just a little courtesy to spend time writing questions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that works according to the OPs data/information provided (using a non-slash delimiter to avoid escaping slashes):

```
preg_replace('#%([a-z]+)\|([a-z/]+)%#', '<a href="\2">\1</a>', $html);
```

Using a non slash delimiter, would alleviate the need to escape slashes.

Outputs:

```
hello <a href="/worldlink/">world</a> again
```

---

**The Explanation**

Why yours did not work. First up the `|` is an `OR` operator, and, in your example, should be escaped. Second up, since you are using `/`'s or expect slashes it is better to use a non-slash delimiter, such as `#`. Third up, the slash needed to be added to list of allowed matches. As stated before you may want to include a bit more options, as any type of word with numbers underscores periods hyphens will fail / break the script. Hopefully that is the explanation you were looking for.

Comment: This is only "fully correct" for a _very_ stringent subset of all URLs.

Comment: Modified the first line to appease the picky ones. @Tomalak, yea technically speaking it was not. But as far as what was given in the main post as an example and desired output, it was a fully correct version for that. The OP did not state he needed the range to be broadened, if he had the answer(s) would have been different.

Comment: @BradFJacobs: It's quite clear what he's trying to do, I think, and that is to linkify URLs. My answer doesn't give him a full solution for that either, but it _does_ point out that `([a-z/]+)` is hardly an URL-matching capture; I think your answer would be even better if it did this too.

Comment: @Tomalak, I added the "Explanation" section (a while ago), which does state: "As stated before you may want to include a bit more options, as any type of word with numbers underscores periods hyphens will fail / break the script."  It could be expanded upon to be a bit more descriptive, however.

Comment: @BradFJacobs: Oh yes, I hadn't seen that edit yet. :) I love your `13 minutes == "a while"`.

Comment: @BradFJacobs: Excellent explanation, thanks. I know it will require more expressive matching but I actually wanted to work that bit out for myself once the basic code worked.

Comment: @Tomalak :) Yea, "a while: a period of indeterminate length (usually short) marked by some action or condition" lol  @khany, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The slashes "/" are not included in your allowed range `[a-z]`. Instead use

```
preg_replace('/%([a-z]+)\|([a-z\/]+)%/', '<a href="\2">\1</a>', $html);
```

Comment: You also need to escape `|` and `/`.

Comment: Or use a different delimeter and the / would then be fine. (such as `#`)

Comment: And probably want to broaden the search range, in case user has a link like `Page.HTML` later down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression:

```
'/%([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)%/'
```

Is only capturing one thing. The `|` in the middle means "OR". You're trying to capture both, so you don't need an OR in there. You want a literal | symbol so you need to escape it:

```
'/%([a-z]+)\|([a-z\/]+)%/'
```

The `/` character also needs to be included in your char set, and escaped as above.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what the heck is RHS?

Comment: Right-Hand Side. You [sort of] fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex (`/%([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)%/`) reads this way:

> Match `%` followed by `+` (= one or
>   more) `a-z` characters (and store this
>   into backreference **#1**).
>
> Or (the `|`):
>
> Match `+` (= one or more) `a-z`
>   characters (and store this into
>   backreference **#2**) followed by a
>   `%`.

---

What you are looking for is:

```
preg_replace('~%([a-z]+)[|]([a-z/]+)%~', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $html);
```

Basically I just escaped the `|` [regex meta character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) (you can do this by either surrounding it with `[]` like I did or just prepending a backwards slash `\`, personally I find the former easier to read), and added a `/` to the second capture group.

I also changed your [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) from `/` to `~` because tildes are much more unlikely to appear in strings, if you want to keep using `/` as your delimiter you also have to escape their occurrences in your regex.

It's also [recommended](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) that you use the `$` syntax instead of `\` in your replacement backreferences:

> `$replacement` may contain references
>   of the form `\\n` or (since PHP 4.0.4)
>   `$n`, with the latter form being the
>   preferred one.

Comment: hmm. thanks but what i get with this is '<a href="hello">world again' so everything exvept the closing '</a>'

Comment: @khany: I get `hello <a href="/worldlink/">world</a> again`, and there isn't any major difference between my regex and the answer you accepted, so my guess is that you misread the result you got..?

Comment: yes sorry the php parser i was using returned false results. Once I uploaded it to my server it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me:

```
preg_replace('/%([a-z]+)\|([a-z\/]+)%/', '<a href="\2">\1</a>', $html);
```

Comment: yes this worked thank you. and thanks to all the contributors on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't escape the `|`, and doesn't include the proper characters for the URL.

Here's a basic <sup>[live](http://www.ideone.com/xKNk7)</sup> example supporting only a-z and slashes:

```
preg_replace('/%([a-z]+)\|([a-z\/]+)%/', '<a href="\2">\1</a>', $html);
```

In reality, you're going to want to change those `[a-z]+` blocks to something more expressive. Do some searches for URL-matching regular expressions, and pick one that fits what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = "hello %world|/worldlink/% again";

echo preg_replace('/([A-ZA-z_ ]*)%(.+)\|(.+)%([A-ZA-z_ ]*)/', '$1<a href="$3">$2</a>$4', $html);

output:
hello <a href="/worldlink/">world</a> again
```

here is a working code : http://www.ideone.com/0qhZ8